# Update/Remove items in Ember Array

Tags: ember.js

I'm doing prototype small app on emberjs for my project.

It's here - [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udinar/26/edit)

I have a list of transactions, which are displayed to the user. User may update or delete some of it.
For example, after update - transaction general status must be change on "Done" if both user status is "Done" (see properties of App.Transaction model).
After "Remove" user action is simply remove from array :)

How it is correctly implemented in ember.js methodology with Ember Arrays?

P.S. Pay no attention to that transaction list is static, in the future I would use ajax-request on load of app for fill transaction list. Currently, statics is made for simplicity.

Thanks.

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895629/add-delete-items-from-ember-data-backed-arraycontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udinar/33/edit).
I've changed a few things, instead of passing the `id` when updating a transaction we pass now the transaction itself, so you can call `setProperties` on it and set the general_status to `Done`. I've also changed this behavior when deleting a transaction. And when adding a transaction you where using always the same id which is not optimal, I've used `Ember.uuid` to get always on creation a new id for your new record.
Have a look at the changed code to see the changes.

> As a side note I should mention that you overall approach is not quite following ember's conventions, but ember is flexible enough to make it work anyway :)

Let me know if this is what you where looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want to understand more deeply an ember's conventions of app development. From official docs I understand a basic entities of ember, but don't clear understand links between its. Sorely lacking use cases ember.js for real projects in line with its true concept of app developing. If you show me one - it's will be very cool :)

Comment: Take a look at emberwatch.com it contains a lot a information, tutorials and screencasts to help you get up and running with ember.js - Good luck :)